# Перегрузка присваивания с использованием больше одного элемента

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

У меня есть класс Time,  с собственными переменными hour, minute, second. Я хочу, чтобы можно было сделать так:

```
Time ex2(5, 5, 5);
ex2 = (10, 10, 10);
```

Но при попытке перегрузить оператор тремя переменными подобным образом:

```
Time& operator = (const int, const int, const int);
```

И реализовать его примерно подобным образом:

```
Time& Time::operator=(const int hour, const int minute, const int second)
{
   itsHour = hour;
   itsMinute = minute;
   itsSecond = second;
}
```

Мне выдает ошибку "слишком много параметров для данного оператора". Кто-нибудь знает как это реализовать или это в принципе невозможно?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Оператор всегда, при любой перегрузке имеет один и тот же синтаксис. Грубо говоря, вы не можете сделать `!` бинарным оператором или `=` - оператором с тремя аргументами.

Но вы можете использовать присвоение самого `Time`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Time
{
    int h,m,s;
    Time(int h, int m, int s = 0):h(h),m(m),s(s){};
    Time(const Time&) = default;
    Time& operator =(const Time&) = default;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Time e(2,3,4);
    e = {5,6,7};
    cout << e.h <<":"<<e.m<<":"<<e.s<<endl;
    e = {4,3};
    cout << e.h <<":"<<e.m<<":"<<e.s<<endl;
}
```

(см. https://ideone.com/xum1iG)

Answer (score 4):

Оператор присваивания по-определению оперирует только с двумя операндами. Однако во второй можно запихнуть несколько элементов:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct foo
{
    void operator =([[maybe_unused]] ::std::initializer_list<int> items) {}
};

int main()
{
    foo f{};
    f = {1, 2, 3};
    return 0;
}
```